# Multi merge somes csv into a dataframe in r

Tags: r

I have some .csv files in a folder (they have the same column format) and I want to merge all csv files into a `data.frame`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please try reading up on how to ask a question, that can be answered by others: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. There are several ways to provide data, probably adding the output of dput(<yourData>) or dput(head(<yourData>)) to your question is sufficient. Avoid adding code or alphanumeric output as images. Consider how to make a good example: stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/… and see how you can change your question accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that all your files are in `your_path` variable, and that all the csv files have the same column name and format, and there is no need for a special encoding,

I found it easier to do this with `data.table`

```
files <- list.files(your_path, full.names = F, pattern = '.csv$')
dt <- rbindlist(lapply(files, fread),use.names = T,fill = T)
#or 
dt <- rbindlist(lapply(files, function(f) fread(f, sep = ';')),use.names = T,fill = T)
```